# What happens to the velocity map image if the plane of polarization is not on the plane of the detector?

Tags: angular-momentum, electrons, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, molecular-dynamics

In an electron Velocity Map Imaging (in Velocity Map Imaging in general) it is required that the plane of polarization to be parallel to the plane of the detector (in other words, plane or polarization lie on the same plane of the detector).. A Reference: E.R.Grumbling et al. J.Chem. Educ., 2011, 88, 1515-1520.  I have following questions:

1) What happens if the plane of polarization is perpendicular to the detector? We won't get the Velocity Map Image?

2) What if we use a non polarized light? How the image look like in this case?

General concepts of Velcoity Map Imaging (VMI) and VMI spectrometers can be found in several literatures and books. But everywhere it is saying about the polarized light and specifically the plane of polarization parallel to the plane of detector!

An interesting article for further reference: R.Mabbs et al., Chem. Soc. Rev., 2009, 38, 2169-2177.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want how you choose the polarization of the light. The polarization of your light determines the recoil of your electron and your ion. In photoelectron vmi you would like to see the angular distribution of how the electron detaches from the molecule, so you should select the polarization of your light such that the velocity vector of you electrons makes the biggest projection on your detector, that is, parallel.

However, there are applications, specifically in ion vmi for collision experiments, that want the opposite. There people want to see the recoil from a collision that has happened before you ionize the molecule, so if the recoil is in the plane of your detector you smear out your resolution. (For ammonia the recoil of the ion due to the photoelectron is already 12 m/s, while the state of art vmi detectors have resolutions below 5 m/s per pixel). Note that vmi was actually developed by people doing collision experiments (Houston and Chandler, Eppink and Parker).

Whether velocity map imaging works depends mostly on the ion optics in combination with the size of the ionization volume, not on the laser polarization.

You can do vmi with unpolarized light but you'll loose resolution/information this way.

Answer (score -1):

The plane of polarization is perpendicular to the direction of propagation.  If the plane of polarization is perpendicular to the detector, the light is parallel to the detector; therefore, none will hit the detector.